# Combine code coverage results in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage, karma-coverage

I have an Angular 6 project which run with .NET Core 2.0.

I'm using `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` to get JavaScript code coverage and mscover to get C# code coverage (I am thinking about using open cover). When I integrate with VSTS, it only shows either JavaScript coverage or C# coverage. It never shows the combined one. Is there a way to combine these two?